# How to set Meteor helper to true for one of many templates?

Tags: jquery, templates, event-handling, meteor, view-helpers

**I'm stuck on how to properly set a boolean template helper to true for one item only and get that to the template .  How do I do that?**

I'm trying to set one of many articles to true, to display some additional information about the article.  I might have 100 articles in a template.  And I want to trigger a `mouseover` boolean on that particular template, then set a helper that is boolean to true upon the `mouseover` to trigger the display of additional html.

I've got the `mouseover` down:

```
'mouseover .hover-check': function () {
  console.log('hover-check works for *one* particular item');
  // need to set boolean here - tried the below code
  Session.set('showHover', true);    // Tried various versions of this...
}
```

For the above I also tried stuff like:

`this.hover`

`Session.set('this.hover');`

and

`Session.set('this.hover', true);`

but didn't get that to the template correctly.  It does correctly get a single article though.  So it seems that setting the variable correctly and getting that to the template is where my trouble is.

I also have a helper:

```
Template.articleItem.helper({
  showHover: function () {
  //Where I need help. I've tried:
  return showHover;  //Sets hoverCheck to true for each of 100 articles but I only want the hovered one to have hoverCheck as true
  }
});
```

There's also the question of how do I send the `showHover === true` to the template.  I've tried various ways like:

`{{showHover}}` Which seems to be how the [docs say to call it](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_helpers) (although they don't show how to close it).  And also `{{#if showHover}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using reactivity for dealing with hover states is, slightly speaking, an overkill. Such things are easily handled by css alone:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="boxContent">...</div>
  <div class="boxExtra">...</div>
</div>

.boxExtra {
  display: none;
}

.box:hover .boxExtra {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do sounds very similar to how a 'selected' player gets highlighted in the [leaderboard example](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/examples/leaderboard).

Since both your helper and your mouseover event have access to some context from the template calling them you can make use of that information.

```
// new event
'mouseover .hover-check': function () {
   Session.set('showHover', this._id);    //can be any field in the article that is unique between articles
}

//new helper
Template.articleItem.helpers({  //fix typo in helpers
  showHover: function () {
    return Session.equals( 'showHover', this._id );  //again I use _id but just match it to whatever you set with mouseover.
  }
});
```

And in your template your idea of using an #if block seems correct:

```
//in articleItem template
{{#if showHover}}
  extra content...
{{/if}}
```

It may also be easier just to include {{showHover}} in the articleItem template and then instead of return a boolean from your helper, return whatever it is you want to add.  Text, a subtemplate...

Comment: I think I'll spend more time with Meteor's examples!!